# Javascript event listener refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have some javascript that I inherited for my job. In this javascript we have a side bar that is constantly updated(every 1 - 10 or so minutes). In the script we parse and process the AJAX from the server and then we call an interesting function.

```
function renewClicks(){
    $('.classElem').unbind('click'); 
    $('.classElem2').unbind('click');
    $('.classElem3').unbind('click'); 

    $('.classElem').click(elm1funct); 
    $('.classElem2').clikc(elm2funct);
    $('.classElem3').click(elm3funct);  
}
```

Where .classElem is a css class selector that is appended to each image that is added to the page. And elmfunct is a function that is written to handle the click. This runs on each update (deauthorizing valid already added elements and then re adding them all). I want to know if there is a way I can possibly attach a listener on the body element in the DOM so that all of the image elements added to the page and that inherit the css class will already be handled and therefore not unregistered and re-registered on each update.

Thank you for any info you can provide.

Comment: You should use delegation with the `on` method of jQuery to handle this, so that you don't have to keep unbinding/rebinding these clicks. Without seeing your HTML code, it would be hard to tell you more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could try this:

```
$('body').on('click','.classElem',elm1funct)
         .on('click','.classElem2',elm2funct)
         .on('click','.classElem3', elm3funct);
```

From [jQuery's docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

Comment: And this will work for each instance that exists in the page at any given time? So lets say I have a magnifying glass icon and I add that to 13 div elements. Will each magnifying glass have the correct event handler assigned? I just want to be thorough.

Comment: Yes by applying `.on()` to the `'body'`, `document` or an ancestor of those elements, the functions assigned on click will work for all elements matching your class selectors, even new ones

Comment: For the sake of performance, delegated event handlers should be attached as close to the target (`.classElem`, etc) as possible. If the target `.classElem` will always be within a div with the ID `myDiv`, use `$('#myDiv').on('click', '.classElem', elm1funct)`.

Answer (score 11):

As @crush mentioned, use an event delegated approach to avoid unbinding and re-binding events:

```
$(document).on('click', '.classElem', elm1funct);
```